# How to control Merge order in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

How to control Merge order in bitbucket?

ex )

1. DEV -> STG PR AND MERGE OK
2. STG -> MAIN PR AND MERGE OK
3. DEV -> MAIN PR AND MERGE X
4. STG -> DEV PR AND MERGE X

I try to set up branch restriction... but i cant find it.